# What's the fastest way to create an extremely large number of elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I need to create about 1 million rows for a table, and I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to do it. I'm obviously not appending them all to the DOM; I just store them in an array. But even just

```
const createRow = function() {
    const row = document.createElement("span");
    row.classList.add("row");
    allRows.push(row);
}
```

takes ~1.5 seconds to create all million rows. Once I start adding in children it gets much worse. (I compared this to creating an object instead of an HTML element, and the object is about 4x faster.)

I know that in practice there are better ways to accomplish my ultimate goal that don't involve creating a million rows at once, but I'm just curious: what is the fastest way to create an extremely large number of elements like this?

Comment: What in the world is the point of a DOM with a million table rows? (*e*: "need to" is doing a lot of heavy lifting in this question.)

Comment: Are you saying "1 million" to mean "a lot" or to you literally mean 1,000,000 elements?

Comment: `for` or `while` loop?

Comment: This type of scenario is why lazy loading is a thing. I am hard pressed to think of a scenario where it would be of any incremental value to have all this data loaded to the DOM at once over lazily loading it.

Comment: Get a benchmark by making a static HTML file with your million rows (note that the posted code is creating `<span>` elements, not table rows, but whatever) and see how long it takes for the browser to build the DOM from straight HTML.

Comment: Right now my use-case involves 73,626 rows, but that number is going to grow, so I'm planning my design to be able to support up to a million. But as I mentioned, this is a theoretical question, not a practical one. I don't want advice like "use a different method for your app"; I'm already doing that. This question is just about the fastest way to create a lot of elements.

Comment: Well `.innerHTML` is surprisingly efficient, so that should definitely be something you try: build your list of elements as a big HTML string and then add it to the DOM all at once.

Comment: like this `const searchResults = document.getElementById("searchResults");
const displayRows = (rows) => searchResults.innerHTML = rows.join('');`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat expensive operations like this can get slower the more times you iterate (obviously) - and with 1,000,000 iterations you for sure only want to perform this loop one time.

It's hard to understand your ultimate goal here. I can't imagine why you would want to create HTML elements and then never add them to the DOM at all and only keep them in an array.  I'm going to have to assume you eventually want to show HTML elements in an HTML document because... why else do this?

I think a more performant way to do this would be to build up an HTML string, and then at the end perform a single DOM write.

```js
let htmlStr = '';

const createRow = function(num) {
    htmlStr += `<span class="row">row #${num}</span> `;
}

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  createRow(i);
}

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

The demo is only 100 elements because I don't want to break the stackoverflow site for anyone who runs this code, so please experiment with larger numbers on your own.  Also please not that even if 1,000,000 elements were pre-generated and zero JavaScript was involved at all, just a static document with 1,000,000 elements might not perform well for even a fast computer. That's **a lot** of stuff for a browser to parse!

Comment: I show a few hundred rows at a time by appending those rows to the DOM. It's much faster to create them in advance in the background than to create them at render time, blocking the browser until they're all created.

Comment: @IsaacKing The browser's HTML parser is highly optimized. Have you benchmarked the answer versus your existing method?

Comment: @IsaacKing I would recommend you test out different version with a tool like https://jsperf.app - you can compare the timing/performance of different code blocks working with the same data.  I was going to make one for you but I'm unsure of your actual use cases for it.